# Enabling UITextField when changing SegmentedControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, ios8, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a UIViewController that have 2 segmented controls which are `Takeaway` and `Delivery`, and 5 UITextFields which are `adressField`, `stateField`, `cityField`, `postcodeField` and `phoneField`.

I would like to disable user input for each `UITextfield` except `phoneField` whenever user choose `Takeaway` ,and enable all the `UITextfield` whenever user choose `Delivery`.

My problem is that the `phoneField` doesn't work even though when I logged the value, `phoneField.isEnabled` return `YES`. And all the fields work when I choose `Delivery` segment. What do I miss here?

Also how do I set the segment `Takeaway` as the default state when user enter the view? since currently I need to select the `SegmentedControl` for changes to take effect.

Here's my `IBAction` snippet for the problem.

```
- (IBAction)segmentChanged:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"SEGMENT: %d", [segment selectedSegmentIndex]);

    switch ([segment selectedSegmentIndex]) {
        case 0:
        {
            self.navigationItem.title = @"Takeaway";
            addressField.enabled = N0;
            ...

            // Enable phoneField here.
            phoneField.enabled = YES;
        }
            break;
        case 1:
        {
            self.navigationItem.title = @"Delivery";
            ...
        }
        break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    // code to change the opacity of the textfield.
    [addressField setAlpha:[segment selectedSegmentIndex]==1 ? 1.0f : 0.3f];
    [addressLabel setAlpha:[segment selectedSegmentIndex]==1 ? 1.0f : 0.3f];
    [addressBox setUserInteractionEnabled:[segment selectedSegmentIndex]==1];
}
```

Comment: Did you check the outlets?

Comment: @DavideDeFranceschi Yes, I do. All of it are linked properly. It's already solved though. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is:

```
   [addressBox setUserInteractionEnabled:[segment selectedSegmentIndex]==1];
```

`addressBox` contains `phoneField`, right? It means you disabling user interaction in whole view and it's subviews. Remove this line and handle your textfield separately.

Comment: Yup. It actually contains all those 5 fields. Forgot to mention it. Anyway, I handle the textfields separately and it works fine now. Thanks for the explanation. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];


   [self.segmentCtrl addTarget:self
                            action:@selector(segmentChanged:)
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    //Tag=5 is of phoneTextField
   [self.view viewWithTag:5].userInteractionEnabled = NO;

}


- (IBAction)segmentChanged:(id)sender
{
    int selectedIndex = (int)[self.segmentCtrl selectedSegmentIndex];

   NSLog(@"SEGMENT: %d",selectedIndex );


   switch (selectedIndex)
   {
       case 0:
                    // Takeaway
        [self.view viewWithTag:5].userInteractionEnabled = NO;
            //Tag=5 is of phoneTextField
        break;

       case 1:
                    // Delivery
        [self.view viewWithTag:5].userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        //Tag=5 is of phoneTextField
        break;

       default:
        break;
   }

}
```